# does wp function the_content(); accept another tag inside

Tags: functions, the-content

I want to place some other PHP tag inside the_content() is it possible somehow?

```
<?php the_content(

$custom_attach = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wp_custom_attachment', true );

      $custom_attach = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );

     $name = 'button';

if ( ! empty( $custom_attach ) ) {

    echo '<span class="icon-download">';
    echo '<a href="'.$custom_attach['url'].'">'.$name.'</a>';
    echo '<span>';
} 
); ?>
```

Comment: as you can see, `the_content()` accepts the 'read more link' text and a boolean  'stripteaser' argument... it does not accept any html tags. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/ - you could however use a filter function to append anything after or before or inside the content https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: I'll look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to put your code between the braces in `the_content()`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Maybe this solves your problem?

```
<?php
    $custom_attach = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
    $name = 'button';

    if(!empty($custom_attach)) {
        echo '<span class="icon-download">';
        echo '<a href="'.$custom_attach['url'].'">'.$name.'</a>';
        echo '<span>';
    }

    the_content();
?>
```

This echoes the `<span>` -element with the class `icon-download` first, and then the content of the post.

Comment: I've a custom link, it is just for my registered users. I want to only users registered see my content and custom meta box content. Thanks your answer I'll try it. Can we add here like so '<a href="'.$custom_attach['url'].'">button</a>'; text instead variable '.$name.'

Comment: Well, this answer should do what you want, as far as I can tell. As for replacing the `.$name.` part with `button`; Absolutely. No problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, because custom meta is out of () brackets